# How can I record audio with Pepper from the tablet and get the signal?

Tags: android, tablet, pepper

I am currently using Android Studio with the API 4 of the Pepper SDK and I am trying to record some audio from the tablet. Do you know a way to do so? I already know how to do it with the tablet microphone, but I want to use the Pepper ones.
Thank you for your replies. :-)

Comment: Why do you want to use the tablet, when there is a microphone array on the robot? I think you are making your task harder by not using the robot's API
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice.html

Answer (score -1):

The most straightforward way to start using ALAudioRecorder is to use the Record Sound box in Choregraphe (Multimedia > Sound category).